# Android Studio 2.1.2 Local Unit Test steps

Tags: android, unit-testing

When attempting to run a 'hello world' type 'local unit test' i get the error

```
Test running failed: Instrumentation run failed due to 'java.lang.RuntimeException'
```

Looking at documentation at https://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing/local-unit-tests.html
i have verified the following is in the app/build.gradle

```
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

**I would like concise steps on how to setup 'local unit testing'** from 'File>New>New Project' with an empty activity.

Testing the method `addition_isCorrect` or whole class `.ExampleUnitTest`

Additionally my setup starts an emulated device but I understand that local unit testing did not need a device or emulator?

Also it appears that the `Test Artifact in the Build Variants view.` is obsolete now.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to create a new `JUnit` Configuration.
Not a Android test that seems to work with ApplicationTest.

```
Run>Edit Configurations>Add a new configuration>
```

Choose your module and pick class .ExampleUnitTest